# General Schematic and PWM questions

Tags: led, pcb, pwm, 555

I'm new to EE.  I've made my first schematic:

To explain my project: I have 1 Nichia E21A LED that needs to be powered by any 5V power bank and be user dimmable via a dial (potentiometer.) The PCB and LED will be housed in different modules.

This is a colour sensitive use so I need to keep the LED running 90% of current output to maintain colour temperature, thus needing a PWM for dimming.

I've wired up a TLC555, however I need help with the duty cycle. I need the maximum duty cycle to be around 45% when **the dial is turned to max** so that I have around 110 lumens.

How can this be done?

Additional questions:

1. A bit of a rookie question but I'm having a lapse in logic:  Are my components wired up appropriately to the 5V out?
2. Is running the LED at 700mA but having the maximum duty cycle around 45% going to yield temperature issues? The LED is  going to be worn near the face.
3. Is my inductor value okay?

P.S. As shown on the schematic, all of the passive components values are final except the 'Switching controller' and 'Pot. Setup'

[Datasheet for LED driver](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/AP5724WG-7_C154870.pdf).

[Datasheet for TLC555](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1810181625_Texas-Instruments-TLC555QDRG4_C7707.pdf).

[Datasheet for LED](http://www.nichia.co.jp/specification/products/led_spec/NVSWE21AT-E(3822I)R70%20R8000%20R9050%20R9080.pdf)

[image]

Comment: I don't get this: `I need to keep the LED running 90% of current output.` and `I need the max duty cycle to be around 45% when the dial is turned to max.`. I know that my English is terrible but I really don't understand this. You want to drive the LED with 630mA (90% of 700mA) and you want the duty-cycle to be **max** %45. How is this even possible? Am I missing something? I'm ready to answer all of your questions but that part confuses me. Sorry.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thank you for your response.
Allow me to clarify:

1. I guess this isn't relevant to my question and is misleading, I apologize. I mean that I need the LED to be running at the factory proposed forward current to maintain color temperature.

2. At 700mA the LED gives around 240 lumens. I only need around 110 lumens. Since the LED is PWM dimmed, a 100% duty cycle (or when the potentiometer is turned all the way to the right), will give 240 lumens. In my case, I need only a %45 duty cycle when the potentio is turned all the way to the right.

I hope this clears things up

Comment: Now it makes sense. So you need PWM dimming to prevent CCT shift, and thus you need 700mA **peak** current. And a luminous flux of 110 lumens is enough for your application, that's why you want the duty-cycle to be 45% max. Okay then. My answer is coming.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. you cannot PWM that Boost converter and expect it to be stable. But if you found it works without much overshoot, ok.

THese are excellent LEDs but around but range around 50 Lumens/ W but I see 5 LEDS per board and that needs a heatsink if using 2W to get 110 Lumens from 5 LEDs after some calibration.

using any PWM controller FET or 555 timer and ?15V is the simple way and choose series R’s around Pot to design range limits.

No worries then about color shift from cool operation but it does shift with temp rise and current.

You may want to Get a portable Lux meter or calibrated camera light sensor to verify light sensor..

So for 110 Lumens you only need 2.5 W with margin and then ambient air flow or metal sink then 2.5V/5x3V=160 mA or so at 100% d.f. and 3x this from 5V or 1.25 this current from 12Vin.

For max heatsinking with CPU cooler 5 Leds x 5W=25W and 1200 Lumens is my guess not seeing the datasheet

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am only powering 1 LED. Here is the datasheet: http://www.nichia.co.jp/specification/products/led_spec/NVSWE21AT-E(3822I)R70%20R8000%20R9050%20R9080.pdf

Comment: Which P/N? you only need 3.3V supply and <350 mA with current sensor 50mV full scale and comparator with analog V controlled current for ≈ 1W controlled by scaling down 3.3V to 50mV for desired 110 Lumen. Using a FET or BJT driver with 1W heatsink

Answer (score 0):

> I've wired up a TLC555, however I need help with the duty cycle. I need the max duty cycle to be around 45% when the dial is turned to max so that I have around 110 lumens.

First of all, I have to say that **you can't drive a single LED (V<sub>F</sub>=3V) with a boost-converter directly from a 5V supply**. You need at least two of them connected in series so that the total load voltage will be higher than the supply voltage. The inductor value is okay unless you use a single LED.

**EDIT:** If you really have to drive a single LED then you should go for a buck/step-down regulator instead. [This one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3405a.pdf) may be a good choice *(I'm not a TI employee and not advertising)*: It enables the designer to drive a single LED at 1A with PWM dimming.

---

About the PWM oscillator, your configuration looks correct but nevertheless, I've modified your circuit a bit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX7PMR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Replaced the diodes with 4148s as 4148 is a switching diode (i.e. faster than 4001).
- Decreased R3 to 1k as it influences the minimum duty-cycle (i.e. the higher the resistance the higher the allowed minimum duty-cycle).
- Increased the potentiometer value to 100k. Because it should be higher enough so that we can neglect the effect of R3 and the internal resistances of the diodes.

The total period is determined by the total resistance between the anode of D3 and the cathode of D2. The duty cycle increases as the potentiometer wiper approaches the D3 (anode). Likewise, the duty-cycle decreases as the potentiometer wiper approaches D2 (cathode).

So, to limit the maximum duty-cycle, a resistor should be placed between the pot and the anode of D3:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl4kxC.png)</sup>

The total period is still determined by the total resistance: 100k + 82k. The minimum duty-cycle is still 0%. And the maximum duty cycle is now
$$ 
\mathrm{ D_{max} = \frac{82k}{82k+100k}=0.45}
$$.

If you want to increase the minimum duty-cycle then you can place a resistor between the potentiometer and the cathode of the D2.

---

The LED is a high-power LED so it gets warmer is it operates. It may get broken down if it's not cooled properly. Placing it on an aluminum PCB and attaching an aluminum heatsink would help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. What do you think should be done since I am running only 1 LED? Relating to the inductor and that my load voltage is less than the supply voltage. 
P.S. Your english is fine, perhaps better than most

Comment: @HazenAL You should go for a buck/step-down regulator. [This one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3405a.pdf) may be a good choice. I'm putting this into my answer. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you again. I have changed over to the LM3405, and made a change to the dimmer circuit. Instead of 100K and 82K, I have changed them to 10K and 8.2K respectively because it is easier for me to source parts. As a result C4 is a 10nF now. However, I have a question regarding the inductor value: I have used L = (3.3+0.12)/(0.7*0.6*1.6) = 5.1uH, based on page 20 of https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1809291613_Texas-Instruments-LM3405XMK-NOPB_C94835.pdf . I have also calculated the peak inductor current to be 0.91A. On LCSC the smallest 5.6 uH I can find is with 5A, Is that ok?